# How do I reference a 'user_id' on a model, but named as two different attributes 'poster_id' and 'receiver_id'? - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

This is my `Feedback` model:

```
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :user
end
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: feedbacks
#
#  id          :integer         not null, primary key
#  poster_id   :integer
#  receiver_id :integer
#  content     :string(255)
#  created_at  :datetime
#  updated_at  :datetime
```

This is my `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many    :feedback
end
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  email      :string(255)
#  f_name     :string(255)
#  l_name     :string(255)
#  username   :string(255)
#  role_id    :integer
#  picture    :string(255)
#  about_me   :string(255)
#  website    :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
```

What I would like to do is retrieve all the feedback for a particular user. But, at my console, when I do `t = User.first` and then `t.feedback`, I get the following error:

```
 Feedback Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "feedbacks".* FROM "feedbacks" WHERE "feedbacks"."user_id" = 1
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: feedbacks.user_id: SELECT "feedbacks".* FROM "feedbacks"  WHERE "feedbacks"."user_id" = 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: feedbacks.user_id: SELECT "feedbacks".* FROM "feedbacks"  WHERE "feedbacks"."user_id" = 1
```

Now that is saying that I have no column `user_id` in my Feedbacks table, which makes sense - because I don't.

What I really want to happen is, I want to store the `user_id` of a user that `posts` feedback as the `poster_id`, and when someone receives feedback I want the `user_id` to be stored in the feedback object as `receiver_id`.

How do I do that?

Thanks.

P.S. Using Rails 3.1...if that has any bearing.

P.P.S. In my `User` model the `has_many :feedback` line looks weird, because I know it should be plural. But `has_many :feedbacks` looks even worse :| What should I do for that too?

P.P.P.S. I looked at the `foreign_key` attribute of associations, but wasn't sure how to get it to work in this situation - would the association be `belongs_to :poster_id, :foreign_key => user_id`? That looks weird and doesn't seem to fit the description in the api documentation of the `foreign_key` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your associations should be defined like this:

```
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :poster, :class_name => 'User'
    belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => 'User'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :feedbacks_as_poster, :foreign_key => :poster_id, :class_name => 'Feedback'
    has_many :feedbacks_as_receiver, :foreign_key => :receiver_id, :class_name => 'Feedback'
end
```

If you are not sure about what the association name means or you don't like the name, you should possibly think about a little bit more about your model, maybe the naming doesn't reflect what you're trying to model with your objects.

Comment: I made these changes. But now when I run `t.feedback`, I get this error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'feedback' for #<User:0x000001017a2748>` What could be causing this?

Comment: There is no **feedback** method on user, the associations are called **feedbacks_as_poster** and **feedbacks_as_receiver**.